# Printer icon in version 10+

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, curated-data

I would like to make a button which prints something.
I would like to use a printer icon on the button, if possible. 
Is such an icon or symbol present and usable in *Mathematica* 10+ ?

Comment: "Print" as in printing on paper, or print onto the screen?

Comment: The button will actually print on screen some settings. So I just want a small button with some "printer" icon. A label will explain the exact purpose of the button

Answer (score 8):

There are quite a few icons available through `Entity`:

```
Entity["Icon", "Printer"]["Image"]
```

[image]

Comment: +  1 Another great answer! Thank you Brett

Answer (score 5):

I was unable to find one after a good amount of spelunking. So instead, I grabbed a "Print" icon from the [Microsoft Visual Studio image library](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17794.visual-studio-how-to-get-high-quality-icons-using-image-library.aspx) and imported it into *Mathematica*. Here is a snippet to get it:

```
printIcon = Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPSmNhYGAoZgUSnrmJ6alpTCAuB5AISix3LCpKrAwWAHJC84oz0/NSUzzzSlLTU4sskpiBggJQDDLh////VMHfvn37TwrGpt/JyYkojE8/IXuprR+bHDH60cXIwehmItOk6qfU/sGkH1/YE1JHSD++dEyMX7ClPVLzELXyLAgHgwoBp8oSaAEC4gWV5qQWcwEZzvk5+UXBBYnJqcGgYiPI3QlNEQ+o9AGWLEU5qYllmXnpYJmQotJUAMRE97s="]
```

This should yield the icon [image: icon]

---

If, like me, you prefer the old-style circa Windows 3.1 icons, this one is from Visual Basic 4:

```
printIcon = Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPSmNhYGAoZgUSnrmJ6alpTCAuB5AISix3LCpKrAwWAHJC84oz0/NSUzzzSlLTU4sskpiBggJQDGIfoAww4AZYFf/HAfCoRzMWv2KqGI7pBYKGo5H4gwVNGcEQJtJkTJfjMr8BBrBagake6EsIQjaWJCchm4zfy1idQaR/SQXA6AsGZSOnyhJoBgLxgkpzUou5gAzn/Jz8ouCCxOTUYFBWCXJ3QlPEA2SAclZRTmpiWWZeOlgmpKg0FQCbVZSm"]
```

which yields the icon [image: icon]

Here is a larger version:

```
printIcon = Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPSmNhYGAoZgUSnrmJ6alpTCAuB5AISix3LCpKrAwWAHJC84oz0/NSUzzzSlLTU4sskpiBguJALAHEIPYBGgMG4gAx5vwnBAiaQ4whxJuDyy/0dAzxhhBpDh4fYcpS7hisRpEaMlgZZABkvcimEQ/QXEIw2PGbQ6F30PxFiXsOoIYGMeZgdcABbEGE3xxgPMMRpjnERxYec5BNoDCccXmWSIDLL2SYg0sLGZ6iBQgGVV9OlSXQigvECyrNSS3mAjKc83Pyi4ILEpNTg0FVVJC7E5oiHiADVKMV5aQmlmXmpYNlQopKUwEGKsJz"]
```

which yields the icon [image: icon]

Comment: +1 Thanks J.M I like it very much